# how displaying money amount in blackjack android game development

Tags: java, android, blackjack

I'm new to android development and I was just wondering how I should store the money value the player current has? Should i store it as a string in string.xml or should i make it an int in a method? Also how should i make the deck of cards. Should i use an array? I was told you shouldnt store it as a string and i dont know how you can display it when you launch the app if its not stored as a string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  <TextView
        android:background ="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cash"
        android:padding="5dip"
        /> 
 Im currently storing it in a textview
```

Comment: you are not storing it in a text view.  You are displaying it in a text view.  MVC might not be the end all, but if you see the word View then chances are it's not storage. ( there are exceptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on the deck of cards, but store the money as a float.  It is not an int.  displaying it is simple as since java can make a float a string by simply adding the float to an empty string

str = "" + flt;   complicated?  How?

```
protected boolean store_cash(){
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GENERAL", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putFloat("cash", mCash);
        return editor.commit();
}
protected void load_cash(){
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GENERAL", 0);
 mCash = settings.getFloat("cash", (float) 0.0);
}
```

with that it's just a matter of setting the title of the textview

```
protected void display_cash(){
    TextView cash = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.cash);
    cash.setText( "$" + mCash);  //formatting may be required..  google is your friend
}
```

Comment: ok thank you! I'm learning android by myself for the final project in AP Comp sci and this helps alot! I have 1 more question, how would i edit the cash amount?

Comment: what do you mean edit it?  You mean change the value say when you win a hand?   mCash += 20;   store_cash(); display_cash();  PS.. an upvote or marking an answer as an answer would be cool.

Comment: Just one thing; money is NOT a float. Floats are not precise and has rounding errors. When working with money, use BigDecimal instead.